# Route traffic through different interfaces randomly

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, vpn, routing

I'm connected to one server from multiple VPN [pptp] connections and each connection gives me a limited bandwidth.

When I connect to multiple vpns windows sends all traffic through the last connected vpn (due to metric in interfaces) even if I add the same metric manually from cmd with a `route add ...` command to all interfaces that connected to vpn - still windows sends all traffic through one of them.

How do I force windows to send traffic throw each of these vpn connections(interfaces) randomly?

Is there software that can do this for me?

Do I have to write a program that listens to all outgoing traffics and sends traffic throw each of these interfaces randomly?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no VPN that can be used with other VPN services at the same time. You can set some programs go with VPN traffic, other programs use the original network. For more details, refer to this instruction: http://www.flyvpn.com/FlyVPN-VPN-Client-3-Specific-Traffic-Via-VPN-Tutorial.html.

Comment: It would be better to include the actual instructions in your answer, to work around possible link decay.

Comment: But you can dial multi VPNs using windows VPN service.